# difference between $this and $this->ci in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, variables, php

hi i am using codeigniter , in my controller constructor sometimes i use `$this` sometimes `$this->ci`

in two constructors i have use like this

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->ci =& get_instance();
    $this->ci->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->ci->load->library('catalog/CatalogManager');
}

function __construct() 
    {
    parent::__construct ();
    $this->ci = & get_instance ();
    $this->load->library ( 'auth_lib' );
    $this->load->library ( 'session' );
    }
```

when passing data to view i use

`$this->ci->data` and `$this->data` in above two cases .

neither gives errors , but i am confused , what is the correct use.

please help...........

Comment: It's kinda sad that a framework purporting to be php5 requires =& assignments.

Comment: @gview I've never *had to* use `=&` assignment in CI

Comment: @gview it's only there to be backwards compatible with php4 and shouldn't be used - especially not in the above context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All controllers extend the main CI_Controller, so calling something like `$this->load` means accessing the parent method `load()` inside the parent class CI_Controller.

`$this->ci` works because with `$this->ci = &get_instance()` you're calling a reference to the main controller class...again. If you look in the bootstrap file (IIRC. Or the codeigniter.php file) there's the function `get_instance()`, which does nothing but return (by reference) the instance of the CI_Controller class.

So, basically, calling `$this->ci->load` and `$this->load` are the same exact thing, only that the first is unnecessary within a Controller/Model/View because the system is already doing that in the parent class (through the method load).

If you have a look at libraries, for ex., you'll see instead that using `$this->ci->method()` is necessary, because you need to have available all the methods of the CI_Controller, which is a kind of "super class" that drives the whole framework.

Have a look at the loader class and the CodeIgniter class to grasp how CI internally works.

Comment: Damien Pirsy has explained the question well, and I'll say my experience: I found that `&get_instance()` return the current controller which is handling this request, it inherits from the most-base `CI_Controller`; while `$this->ci` specifically means the instance of `CI_Controller`

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the answer above, but actually, load is a variable, not a function. it is a object of the class CI_Loader, when you call $this->load->libray(), in fact it calls the library() function in CI_Loader.

Answer (score -3):

`$this` is nothing. It just use to store the value. It just like a variable.